# webGl shaders uncaught syntax error

Tags: javascript, opengl, webgl

I'm getting  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

```
    <script id="shader-vs" type="text/javascript">
       attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
       uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
       uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
       void main(void) {
       gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
   }
```

Anyone knows how to fix it ? I'm pretty noob in webgl and I got more and more confused.

Comment: Please indicate what library / API / thefile.js you are using...

Answer (score 1):

Change `type="text/javascript"` to anything else, such as `type="x-shader/x-fragment"`. Otherwise your GLSL will be interpreted as javascript.